# Consecutively count the occurrence of a condition R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Sample_No Lab_ID
1234       2
1235       2
1236       2
2344       3
3425       4
2341       5
6756       5
...
```

I want to count how many times each lab_id occurs but the occurances number next to it in a new column of the dataframe to look something like the following

```
Sample_No Lab_ID   Occurrence
1234       2           1
1235       2           2
1236       2           3
2344       3           1 
3425       4           1
2341       5           1 
6756       5           2
...
```

I can get a list of the unique values by using

I could do something like

```
table(df$LAB_ID)
```

but that produces a table summarizing the count

any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution without loading more than a dozen additional packages using `rle`.

```
> x <- c(2,2,2, 3, 4, 5,5)
> 
> cs <- rle(x)
> 
> xy <- cs$lengths
> 
> out <- mapply(
+   FUN = function(x) seq(from = 1, to = x, by = 1),
+   xy
+ )
> 
> data.frame(
+   lab_id = x,
+   occurrence = unlist(out)
+ )
  lab_id occurrence
1      2          1
2      2          2
3      2          3
4      3          1
5      4          1
6      5          1
7      5          2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to count the occurrence of each `Lab_ID` you could either use the `{dplyr}` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df%>% 
  count(Lab_ID, name = "Occurrence")
```

Or you could achive the same using the `{data.table}` package as follows:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(Occurrence = .N),
              by = Lab_ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `tidyverse`, or in this case `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse) # load library

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Lab_id) %>% # for every lab ID
  summarise(Occurence=n()) # count occurence
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `sequence` + `rle`

```
transform(
  df,
  Occurence = sequence(rle(Lab_ID)$lengths)
)
```

gives

```
  Sample_No Lab_ID Occurence
1      1234      2         1
2      1235      2         2
3      1236      2         3
4      2344      3         1
5      3425      4         1
6      2341      5         1
7      6756      5         2
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, Occurence := rleid(Sample_No), Lab_ID][]
   Sample_No Lab_ID Occurence
1:      1234      2         1
2:      1235      2         2
3:      1236      2         3
4:      2344      3         1
5:      3425      4         1
6:      2341      5         1
7:      6756      5         2
```